# Getting CSV Columns' name using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, csv

I must upload large files (+1GB) in CSV format. I must check the column names, and I want to do it before upload process. So, I am trying to read the CSV using JavaScript, following

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

and

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader.readAsBinaryString

It work! But I have to read the complete file, and believe me, the files are too large.

My question is: How can I get the CSV columns' name using JavaScript, without reading the entire file?

Comment: pass file.slice(0, 500) to FileReader instead of just the whole file...  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob.slice  You may need more than 500 bytes, that's just a syntax example...

Comment: once you have the start of the file's contents, split on "\n" and take the [0] prop, then split by comma to get an array of the CSV fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can access all kinds of data about a file without passing it to a `FileReader`.  You can get the size of a file by checking [`file.size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob.size).

Check the documentation for [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) and [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) (`File` inherits `Blob`) to see what else is available to you.